# Get the dimensions of a HDF5 dataset

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

I'm using some HDF5 Files in my C++ program and I have a question regarding the `H5Dopen` function. Is it possible to get the dimensions of a hdf5 dataset in a given file?

```
hid_t file, dset;
herr_t status;
file = H5Fopen (filenameField, H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);
dset = H5Dopen (file, "/xField", H5P_DEFAULT);
```

before I do the next line I want to get the dimensions of `dset`.

```
status = H5Dread (dset, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT,  &readBuf[0]);
```

I only found `H5Dget_storage_size`, but that does not fit my case.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 21):

For this you need to use data**space** functions which are prefixed by H5**S**.

The [HDF5 reference manual](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5Front.html) is organized using these prefixes so it helps to understand that.

#### How to get the dimensions of a dataset

First you need to get the data space from your dataset using [`H5Dget_space`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-GetSpace):

```
hid_t dspace = H5Dget_space(dset);
```

If your data space is *simple* (i.e. not *null* or *scalar*), then you can get the number of dimensions using [`H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5S.html#Dataspace-ExtentNdims):

```
const int ndims = H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims(dspace);
```

and the size of each dimension using [`H5Sget_simple_extent_dims`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5S.html#Dataspace-ExtentDims):

```
hsize_t dims[ndims];
H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(dspace, dims, NULL);
```

The dimensions are now stored in `dims`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, this can be done like this (in case of a simple dataspace, see Simons answer and if necessary check with `bool H5::DataSpace::isSimple() const`):

```
  #include "H5Cpp.h"
  using namespace H5;
  //[...]
  DataSpace dataspace(RANK, dims);
  //[...]
  /*
   * Get the number of dimensions in the dataspace.
   */
  const int rank = dataspace.getSimpleExtentNdims();
```

This line might be redundant in most cases, because the whole task can be done in two lines:

```
  /*
   * Get the dimension size of each dimension in the dataspace and
   * store the dimentionality in ndims.
   */
  hsize_t dims_out[rank];
  const int ndims = dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims( dims_out, NULL);
```

The function `getSimpleExtentNdims()` can be called as a member of the `H5::DataSpace` instance.

These pieces of code are taken from the [examples page](https://bitbucket.hdfgroup.org/pages/HDFFV/hdf5doc/master/browse/html/cpplus_RM/examples.html) (readdata.cpp) of the more recent [HDF5 C++ reference manual](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50073884).

Compile everything with `h5c++` and it should work.